# How to query what users are logged on to a remote server's Terminal Services

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-terminal-services

I've used *quser* before to query users on the local server. I noticed today that it has an option for querying a remote server. However, when I tried it, I keep getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\nimmylebby>quser administrator /SERVER:remote_server
Error 0x00000005 enumerating sessionnames
Error [5]:Access is denied.
```

I'm assuming it's because I do not provide a password? But I do not see an option to provide password. Here is the help doc:

```
C:\Users\nimmylebby>quser /?
Display information about users logged on to the system.

QUERY USER [username | sessionname | sessionid] [/SERVER:servername]

  username            Identifies the username.
  sessionname         Identifies the session named sessionname.
  sessionid           Identifies the session with ID sessionid.
  /SERVER:servername  The server to be queried (default is current).
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the *quser* command? Is there a more appropriate command for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to boot other Remote Desktop users](http://serverfault.com/questions/81876/how-to-boot-other-remote-desktop-users)

Comment: Although this question is about how to use quser, that question is definitely helpful. Thank you Graeme! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you querying to find out if the user named administrator has a session on the remote server?

Is the account under which you're running quser a domain admin or a local admin of the remote server?

Comment: Was not aware that the PC had to be part of the domain. The help text does not describe that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use runas?

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\user "quser /SERVER:servername"
```

Where DOMAIN\user has admin rights on the target server?